# What data sources Snowflake support?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, datasource

As mentioned in the title, I'd like to know what data sources Snowflake supports. I'm not completely sure how to even approach this question. I know you can create an external stage in the cloud storage of supported cloud providers, but what if I want to load data from the Oracle database, for example. What's the best solution in that case, is it to use the ODBC driver, or?

And please feel free to give me any suggestions, or advice on where to continue my research. Also, let me know if any part of my question is unclear so that I can rephrase it :)

Answer (score 4):

Snowflake natively supports AVRo, Parquet, CSV, JSON and ORC. These are landed in a stage for ingestion --- your ELT/ETL tool of choice or even a home-built application must land the data in a stage, either internal or external.
That file is then ingested into Snowflake utilizing a COPY command either automated by said tool or using something like Snowpipe.
We have documentation on Firehose / Kafka pipelines landing data for Snowpipe to ingest either through AUTO_INGEST notifications (limited to external stage) or calling our REST API.

All supported by our documentation, simply google the terms I have mentioned and there will be tons of documentation

Comment: A [good place to start](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-overview.html) and [this one](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide-data-load.html).

Comment: Thank you both! Your answers are very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Multiple existing ETL Tools allow to define Snowflake as destination, supporting a wide variety of sources.

**[Native Programmatic Interfaces](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/ecosystem-lang.html)**

**[Snowflake Ecosystem - Data Integration](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/ecosystem-etl.html)**